# How to share rspec examples across multiple apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, dry

I have a bunch of Rails applications that need to run the same rspec examples. These specs are about enforcing consistent conventions across the organization. I'm familiar with Rspec's shared_example, but AFAIK, they can only be shared within the same application.

Is there a way to share rspec across multiple applications. If it helps, all the applications share a Rails engine.

Comment: It's a good question, but it looks difficult, I didn't research any solution, maybe you should create new solution to a ruby wrapper by yourself

Answer (score 1):

You need to require the shared files using the **full_path** (you can set this path using an ENV variable):

```
require '/home/USERNAME/shared_examples/my_shared_specs.rb'
```

or

```
require ENV['SHARED_EXAMPLE_FILE_PATH']
```

Add that in your spec file and you should be able to call it.

If you want to load more than one file, make sure to require all the files in your rspec `rails_helper.rb` (`spec_helper.rb` if you have an old version) also make sure you load them before the files that use them ([documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/example-groups/shared-examples)).

`rails_helper.rb`

```
...
Dir['/home/USERNAME/shared_examples/*.rb'].each { |file| require file }
...
```

or

```
...
Dir["#{ ENV['SHARED_EXAMPLES_PATH'] }*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
...
```

Just make sure you replace the path I used to the one you have.

Other one a bit more complex will be to create a gem with just the shared examples, and again in your `rails_helper.rb` require the files:

```
...
Dir["#{Bundler.load.specs.find{|s| s.name == <gem_name> }.full_gem_path}/shared_examples_path/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
...
```

This could be a method in the gem.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I don't think RSpec supports that. But this could be approached like a problem of sharing code across projects. So if you already do that in your organisation, I'd stick to that solution, to be consistent. Otherwise, you could try:

1. Creating a gem (e.g. `shared_specs`) with the specs. Require the spec files in the gem's `lib/shared_spec.rb` then, in each application's `Gemfile`, add `gem 'shared_specs', require: false` and `require 'shared_specs'` in `spec/shared_specs.rb`. However, you'd want to publish the gem on your [own gem server](https://github.com/geminabox/geminabox).
2. Use SCM ([git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), [svn](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html), [hg](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository)) submodules to pull the specs from a separate repository into the main one's `spec` directory. This requires familiarity with the SCM and the process can [be](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FeaturesOfLastResort#But_I_need_to_have_managed_subprojects.21) [cumbersome](https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/).
3. The solutions above reduce duplication, but create additional maintenance overhead - they require extra infrastructure and update in the specs means updating every application. Depending on the context (distributed teams with a different pace, applications with basically similar, but slightly different spec requirements, small number of apps, infrequent spec changes), a simple copy & paste of the file with specs might work as well.

(Each option makes certain assumptions, but, my SO points are too low to ask clarifying questions via comments).